Does switching back to real mode switches back the addessing mode?
I have a boot sector that does the following, tested as a floppy in qemu-system-i386:
.code16
movw $0xd00, %bx                           ## machine code: 0xbb 0x00 0x0d
*Switch to Protected mode here, omitted*
.code32
movw $0xd00, %bx                           ## machine code: 0x66 0xbb 0x00 0x0d
*Switch back to real mode here, omitted*
.code16
movw $0xd00, %bx                           ## machine code: 0xbb 0x00 0x0d

This should work fine, but the processor gets confused in the last line, it doesn't move the value and starts jumping around. If I omit the last ".code16" (which adds a 0x66 to the machine code of the last line) then everything works fine. Why is that?
At first I thought that the procesor was not switching back to real mode, that would explain it, but it is kind of switching: after the last line cr0 holds 0x10, and I checked that segmentation works as for real mode.
Complete code:
.code16
  movw $0xd00, %bx   ## machine code: 0xbb 0x00 0x0d
  cli
  lgdt gdt_register
  movl %cr0, %eax
  orb $1, %al
  movl %eax, %cr0
  jmp $0x8, $protected

.code32
protected:
  sti
  movw $0xd20, %bx   ## machine code: 0x66 0xbb 0x00 0x0d        
back_to_realmode:
  cli
  lidtl idt_48
  movl %cr0, %eax
  andb $0xfe, %al
  movl %eax, %cr0
  jmp $0x0, $real

.code16
real:
  sti
  movw $0xd00, %bx
## gdt, idt, magic number, omitted..


https://wiki.osdev.org/Real_Mode suggests that in order to re-enter real mode, you have to go via 16-bit protected mode.

@NateEldredge is correct. While you are in real mode, you are actually in real mode where the default operand size is still 32-bits. When you did jmp $0x0, $real (without first entering 16-bit protected mode) you ended up using cached descriptor information for CS (Code segment) that was used for 32-bit mode (DB was still 1 in the CS descriptor where it should be 0 for 16-bit code). As a result you ended up in real mode but the processor was still decoding assuming the default operand size was 32-bit (and not 16-bit).

@MichaelPetch: Oh right, because setting segment registers in "real mode" only updates the segment base, not any of the other internal state ("descriptor cache") like limit. Or for CS, the current default operand-size.

Yes, exactly @PeterCordes . For the OP: I have created some code in NASM (not gnu assembler, but you should get the idea) that enters protected mode; does nothing; and then comes back to real mode via 16-bit protected mode. The code is here: https://pastebin.com/gmnxJyqt

@MichaelPetch thank you! How does it work though? I thought in protected mode the "internal state" of a segselector is saved by the value of the sselector and the gdtr, so that when it used the processor goes to the gdt to look. Is this true, or is the "internal state" of a seg selector saved somewhere else in the processor? If it is saved in the processor, how does the processor know to update when I say change a specific entry in the gdt. If it is not saved in the processor, how does the unreal mode remembers the type of addessing if it has no gdt to go look at the internal state?

The GDT (which is stored in memory) is never read into the CPU as on large table. The LGDT loads a record that says where in memory the GDT is (and its length) but that is it. Descriptors get read from the GDT when you set the value of one of the segment registers (CS, DS, ES, SS, FS, GS). Each one of the segments has a hidden descriptor entry inside the CPU (for speed). When you load a segment register the hidden descriptor entry in the CPU gets updated with the access rights, info, base, and limit. If you reference a memory address the descriptor cache is checked instead of main memory.

If you make a change to an entry in the GDT that information doesn't ever get propagated automatically to the segment registers. If you make a change in the GDT, it is always your responsibility to reload the segment registers yourself. That is why often when you do an LGDT instruction that afterwards you'll often see the segment registers reloaded (you can see that in my code). Any instruction that moves a value into a segment register will force a reload of the entry from the GDT  in memory.

Now real mode is a bit different. The GDT doesn't apply in real mode. When you update a segment register in real mode the only value in the hidden descriptor cache that gets updated is the BASE. All the access rights, flags, and the limit are untouched. So if you come out of protected mode with CS still loaded as a 32-bit Code Selector (with the DB flag set to 1 = default operand size of 32) then that will continue to apply once you hit real mode. Which is what happened in your case. Intel chose to use cached descriptors in real mode behind the scenes for performance reasons.

The concept of unreal mode (entering protected mode and setting the LIMIT of the segment registers to 0xffffffff instead of 0xffff) and returning back to real mode is based on the notion that the limit will continue on in real mode as well. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode . The OSDEV Wiki has some info on the descriptor cache as well https://wiki.osdev.org/Descriptor_Cache

I also recommend reading the Intel Software Development Manual Section 3.4.3 (Segment Registers) which describes the Descriptor Cache.

I made some minor bug fixes to my Pastebin code. You may wish to make sure you have the latest.

I see. So in unreal mode the DB flag is 1 so you can't use real-mode code (e.g. BIOS interrupts) because the operand/address size prefixes of your opcodes will be wrong or missing, that's not very real. You can access high memory, that's also not very real. What is real about unreal mode then? Is it how the segmentation gets applied? in real mode (and in unreal mode) the processor knows that is has to shift the "base" before adding it? Is that the only thing that cr0.bit1 is really enforcing? (if it is not enfdorcing the 16/32 bit addessing)

In 32-bit Unreal mode (where you used the cached descriptor in CS that is set from protected mode) your observation is correct, it is problematic (some environments don't support it). Regular Unreal mode enters protected mode and only updates the data segments (DS, ES, SS, FS, and GS) by setting them with 16-bit descriptors with limits of 0xffffffff (rather than 0xffff) and returns to real mode. The CS descriptor flag DB (size) is what tells the CPU what the default operand size is.

In unreal mode you can do something like mov eax, 0xb8000 mov [eax], 'X' . Normally any memory operand that is above 0xffff would be a problem but in unreal mode the limit has been set to 0xffffffff so this kind of code works. Note: some environments like QEMU skip limit checks to speed up emulation so writing beyond 0xffff even if the limit is 0xffff won't cause a problem (like a GPF). BOCHS is far less forgiving and will attempt to warn you with messages when limits are exceeded. I find for lower level development BOCHS is a better tool.

Thanks, everything is clear now. Do you know if the most used bootloaders usually go to 16-bit Regular Unreal mode or if they switch between real and protected mode? or they go to protected mode and have drivers for everything and they do everything there and then jump back to real mode to jump to the kernel? (supposing that the kernel expects real mode, like linux)

For the most part operating systems try to enter protected mode (or longmode) and never exit. On systems with legacy BIOS often real mode is used to query/set video modes and then enter protected mode (or long mode). OS drivers are written to access hardware directly (MMIO, Ports etc).

I think http://www.rcollins.org/ddj/Aug98/Aug98.html is a nice reference too
